# How to run app as administrator using username and password

Tags: c#

I have a program that runs only with administrator rights (through the context menu). How do I make a script that uses the credentials of the local administrator to run the application?

What i have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //copy from
        string sourcePath = @"\\10.11.11.4\Links\";
        //copy to
        string targetPath = @"e:\RainbowPlus\Links\";
        if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }
        foreach (var srcPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
        {

            File.Copy(srcPath, srcPath.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath), true);
        }

        ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();

        ps.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\RAR.exe";
        //unrar and overwrite to
        ps.Arguments = @"x -o+ e:\RainbowPlus\Links\Links.rar e:\RainbowPlus\Links\";
        Process.Start(ps);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            FileName = @"E:\\RainbowPlus\\Rainbowplus.exe",
            UserName = "username",
            Domain = "my.domain",
            Password = GetSecureString("secretpassword"),
            Arguments = ""
        }
        };
        //proc.Start();
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("E:\\RainbowPlus\\Rainbowplus.exe");

    }

    public static SecureString GetSecureString(string str)
    {
        SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
        foreach (char ch in str)
        {
            secureString.AppendChar(ch);
        }
        secureString.MakeReadOnly();
        return secureString;
    }
```

But i still have UAC promt.
Befor this, i use bat file:

```js
@echo off

REM Check runing program ####

Set ProcessName=rainbowplus.exe
TaskList /FI "ImageName EQ %ProcessName%" | Find /I "%ProcessName%" 
If %ErrorLevel%==0 (echo Close rainbow program) else (goto testnetwork)
pause
exit

REM Network testing

:testnetwork
echo Testing network
pause
ping -n 4 10.11.11.4 | find "TTL=" > nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (goto copy) else (echo Network down)
pause
exit

REM Copy files

:copy
echo Updating files 
pause
xcopy "\\10.11.11.4\Links" "E:\RainbowPlus\Links" /i /q /e /y /h /c
if %errorlevel%==0 (goto startprogram) else (goto error)
:startprogram
echo Succsess
pause
runas.exe /env /profile /savecred /user:"comp5234\Administrator" "E:\RainbowPlus\RainbowPlus.exe"
exit
:error
echo Files was not updated
pause
exit
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: A user should know the admin credentials to run an app as admin. If you're going to substitute them then that negates the whole point of having an admin account in the first place. Your best bet is to either 1. require the user to enter the credentials (best) or 2. Save the credentials into an encrypted file and load that in (Only letting an admin change the file).

Comment: Thanks. Second solution looks like better for me. @TheLethalCoder Can you tall me how i can do this?

Comment: No this isn't a code writing service. Try and do it yourself then come back and ask a new specific question if you have a problem and provide a [MCVE] when you do.

Answer (score 0):

try this. Add the application  manifest file in your project. then add the below line in the manifest file.

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

While working on Visual Studio, right click on Project -> Add New Item and then chose Application Manifest File for adding application manifest file

Comment: I tryed this, but user shouldnt know administrator password. I want the user name and password to be substituted automatically

Answer (score 0):

What works is to impersonate the admin user in your program and then start the external process while being impersonated as the admin user.

The interactive user will still see a UAC confirmation (unless your application is already running with elevated privileges), but they won't have to enter credentials, just click "OK", the credentials of the impersonated admin user will be used.

Use the following source code:

```
private void Impersonate()
{
    IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
    if (LogonUser("adminusername", "", "Password", LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out token))
    {
        throw new Win32Exception();
    }

    WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(token);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Impersonate();
    try
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "ABC.exe";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.Start();
    }
    finally
    {
        RevertToSelf();
    }
}

private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string pszUserName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string pszDomain,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string pszPassword,
    int dwLogonType,
    int dwLogonProvider,
    out IntPtr phToken);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool RevertToSelf();
```

Note that you have to use `UseShellExecute = false`.